# Python youtube_dl DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, youtube-dl

I keep getting this error message, but I installed ffprobe already.  Here is the full traceback

```
[youtube] DTuDLVtMC90: Downloading webpage
[youtube] DTuDLVtMC90: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] DTuDLVtMC90: Extracting video information
[youtube] DTuDLVtMC90: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination:C:\Users\Class2016\Documents\GitHub\data_gen\Pull_Audio\7\7.wav
[download] 100% of 477.19KiB in 00:00                  
WARNING: DTuDLVtMC90: writing DASH m4a. Only some players support this container. Install ffmpeg or avconv to fix this automatically.
ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-bbb67b141a45>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Class2016/Documents/GitHub/data_gen/Pull_Audio/pull_audio.py', wdir='C:/Users/Class2016/Documents/GitHub/data_gen/Pull_Audio')

  File "C:/Users/Class2016/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Class2016/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Class2016/Documents/GitHub/data_gen/Pull_Audio/pull_audio.py", line 75, in <module>
GetAudio()

  File "C:/Users/Class2016/Documents/GitHub/data_gen/Pull_Audio/pull_audio.py", line 42, in __init__
self.__DownloadAudio()

  File "C:/Users/Class2016/Documents/GitHub/data_gen/Pull_Audio/pull_audio.py", line 65, in __DownloadAudio
ydl.download([self.url])

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1966, in download
url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 787, in extract_info
return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 841, in process_ie_result
return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1601, in process_video_result
self.process_info(new_info)

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1947, in process_info
self.post_process(filename, info_dict)

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2014, in post_process
self.report_error(e.msg)

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 604, in report_error
self.trouble(error_message, tb)

  File "C:\Users\Class2016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 574, in trouble
raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)

DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.
```

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions worked or I couldn't figure out how to implement them.  Thanks!

Comment: Unless you explain why none of the other solutions worked, this question probably can't be answered in a non-duplicate way. I've linked it to a question that has a Microsoft specific answer, if the proposed solution does not work, you can (and *should!*) edit your question and explain why.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I think the .exe file is in the wrong path, but I have no idea what path its supposed to be in or how to move it

Comment: According to the answer in the other question *"Just copy "`avprobe.exe`" and all DLLs from "`/win64/usr/bin`" to where "`youtube-dl.exe`" is."*

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Sorry, I know this is a dumb question, but how do I find where that is?